# SSD not detected after booting into linux and GRUB not booting into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

My laptop has two drives:

- an SSD (which came with Windows installed) and
- a HDD (on which I have just finished installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I have 2 issues which are as follows:

1. GRUB loads when I boot into Ubuntu and shows a Windows option but when I select that option, nothing happens. I know that I can use BIOS to boot into windows using windows boot manager but why can't I do it from GRUB? I have attached a screenshot of the section that shows the Windows section from the GRUB config file: [GRUB Windows Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wphrg.png). Also, the

   ```
   sudo os-prober
   ```

   command in the terminal doesn't return anything. I have a feeling this is related to the second problem...
2. When I boot into Ubuntu, it can't seem to find my SSD. It can only detect the hard drive that has Ubuntu installed on it. I have also attached a screenshot of what I get when I type the following command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo parted -l
   ```

   Its output is:

   [image: Command Output]

Is there a way I can access my SSD from Linux and boot into Windows from GRUB or do I have to open BIOS every time I start my computer and choose where I want to boot?

Comment: You show sda, which is an UEFI install. Is Windows UEFI? If so what brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? And/Or you may have Windows fast start up on which must be off for os-prober to see the Windows partitions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Windows being UEFI but when I open BIOS, the UEFI button is selected so I am guessing the answer to your first question is yes. This issue is occuring on Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell G5 laptop. I have carried out all the updates that the SupportAssistant provided by Dell has told me to. Also, I made sure to disable fast startup before installing Ubuntu and it is still off.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report) inquestion above, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Windows is known to turn fast start up back on with updates (which you may not always see). Is drive set for AHCI, if not you need that, but must first install Windows AHCI driver for Winodows.